# how use a require alongside an "If" statement

Tags: php, require

Is it possible to do something like:

```
if ($_GET['type'] = 'all')
   require __DIR__."/details/all.php";
else
   require __DIR__."/details/".$_GET['type'].".php";
```

I'm trying to do this, because the information on the "All.php" file is very different from the other types. Is it possible?

Comment: Write `$_GET['type'] == 'all'`

Comment: Write `$_GET['type'] === 'all'` : - p

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: And by all means... you _really_ want to rely on the client side to load any arbitrary script the user on the client side feels motivated to without you being able to control that? You implement a _mile wide security gap_ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write `===` instead of `=` and also check [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) condition.

```
if(isset($_GET['type']) && ($_GET['type'] === 'all')){
   require __DIR__."/details/all.php";    
}else{
   require __DIR__."/details/{$_GET['type']}.php";
}
```

**Note**:- `=` is an assignment operator and

`==` checks the condition
  and `===` will check condition + datatype also.

Comment: Even better would be `===` and you should place brackets around the second condition for readability.

Comment: @arkascha:  Yes `===` will be more appropriate and I have also added bracket in second condition.